# Modelica and CANBus (General, CANOpen, and/or J1939)

Tags: modelica, can-bus

I have experience with Simulink and CANbus interfaces for both simulation and code generation...  but I really like open source.  For quite awhile Octave has qualified as a MATLAB replacement (at my usage level) but I just recently found out about Modelica.  I have yet to find any information about any blocksets (what term does Modelica tend to use?) for CANbus other than the broken link for Exite from Extessy.

Can anyone provide personal experience or a reference to information on using Modelica with CANbus?  I know that I could write my own blockset, but it seems like the sort of thing someone else would already have done.

Answer (score 2):

The best reference I could find on this topic was [this paper](https://www.modelica.org/events/modelica2009/Proceedings/memorystick/pages/papers/0058/0058.pdf).  It was apparently developed as part of the EuroSysLib project.  I do not know if it is publicly available anywhere.  I would suggest you contact the authors.

Answer (score 1):

another option for simulation of entire ECUs, including CAN is described here:
http://qtronic.de/en/index_news_12_6_ATZ.html
See paper "Building Virtual ECUs Quickly and Economically" in the June 2012 issue of ATZ electronic. Use Modelica to build vehicle simulation models for export as FMU,
and the Silver Basic Software (SBS) to configure CAN emulation based on DBC files,
and run both parts closed-loop in Silver.